# Error using ST_AddPoint for adding a new point to a polyline in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql, postgresql

I have two PostGIS tables, one where I store points, named "*nodes*" and another with where I store multilinestrings, named "*lines*".
I'm trying to append a new vertex to a line using one of the nodes executing a query similar to the following SQL sentence:

```
UPDATE lines SET 
the_geom = ST_AddPoint(the_geom, (select the_geom from nodes where id_node='XXXXX')  )
WHERE id_line='YYYY'
```

But I get:

```
ERROR: lwline_deserialize: attempt to deserialize a line which is really a Invalid type
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it only works with LineString, not MultiLineString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have version 1.5? That's the error you get if you attempt to use `ST_AddPoint()` with a `MULTILINESTRING` geometry.

For this type, you need to specify which part of the line needs to be appended to, then use a messy combination of `ST_Dump()`/`ST_Collect()` to modify that part.

For example, to append the point to the last LineString:

```
SELECT id_line, ST_AsEWKT(ST_Collect(geom))
FROM (
  SELECT id_line, CASE
    WHEN (dump).path[1] = ngeo THEN
      ST_AddPoint((dump).geom, (select the_geom from nodes where id_node='XXXXX'))
    ELSE
      (dump).geom
    END AS geom
  FROM (
    select id_line, ST_NumGeometries(geom) ngeo, ST_Dump(geom) as dump from lines
  ) AS foo
) AS foo
GROUP BY id_line;
```

where `id_line` is your primary key. You can modify this to an UPDATE query.